AWS Athena Parse array of JSON objects to rows
Working with AWS Athena and trying to parse data found in a column with a defined data type of array  so that each JSON object in the array is broke out into a separate row.
when I run this query:
SELECT properties_textarray
FROM "sample"."property_detail" 
where propertyid = '5bb0a33f-3ca6-4f9c-9676-0b4d62dbb195'

the result is this array of JSON objects.
:
[{"updatedDate":"2023-11-16T23:23:27.677639+00:00","city":"Portland","customerName":"SMITH ALBERT","state":"OR","updatedBy":"Bill Armstrong "}, 
 {"updatedDate":"2023-11-16T21:11:11.077907+00:00","city":"Seattle","customerName":"JONES JACKIE L","state":"WA","updatedBy":"Bill Armstrong "}, 
 {"updatedDate":"2023-12-29T19:52:01.276227+00:00","city":"Boise","customerName":"JOHNSON BOB","state":"ID","updatedBy":"Brian Smith "}]

I have tried the CROSS JOIN UNNEST but not getting the results I'm hoping of where the query I'm running for a specific propertyid of data will return each JSON object as a separate row.  I"m planning to use these results for additional processing as needed.

What is the result of select typeof(properties_textarray)? What result are you getting?

This is the response:  array(varchar)

JSON properties will not be extracted for you (at least as far as I know), you can extract them manually. Personally I prefer the cast to array of maps approach, something along the following lines (note the succinct syntax used for unnesting):
-- sample data
with dataset(properties_textarray) as (
values ('[{"updatedDate":"2023-11-16T23:23:27.677639+00:00","city":"Portland","customerName":"SMITH ALBERT","state":"OR","updatedBy":"Bill Armstrong "},
 {"updatedDate":"2023-11-16T21:11:11.077907+00:00","city":"Seattle","customerName":"JONES JACKIE L","state":"WA","updatedBy":"Bill Armstrong "},
 {"updatedDate":"2023-12-29T19:52:01.276227+00:00","city":"Boise","customerName":"JOHNSON BOB","state":"ID","updatedBy":"Brian Smith "}]')
)

-- query
select element_at(json, 'customerName') customerName,
       element_at(json, 'city') city,
       element_at(json, 'state') state,
       element_at(json, 'updatedBy') updatedBy,
       element_at(json, 'updatedDate') updatedDate
from dataset
, unnest(cast(json_parse(properties_textarray) as array(map(varchar, json)))) as t(json);

Output:



customerName
city
state
updatedBy
updatedDate




SMITH ALBERT
Portland
OR
Bill Armstrong
2023-11-16T23:23:27.677639+00:00


JONES JACKIE L
Seattle
WA
Bill Armstrong
2023-11-16T21:11:11.077907+00:00


JOHNSON BOB
Boise
ID
Brian Smith
2023-12-29T19:52:01.276227+00:00



There are other similar approaches, like casting to array(json) and using json_extract or json-query. Also maybe casting to ROW will work too.
UPD

This is the response: array(varchar)

Then I would simply use json_extract_scalar/json_extract:
-- sample data
with dataset(properties_textarray) as (
values (array['{"updatedDate":"2023-11-16T23:23:27.677639+00:00","city":"Portland","customerName":"SMITH ALBERT","state":"OR","updatedBy":"Bill Armstrong "}',
 '{"updatedDate":"2023-11-16T21:11:11.077907+00:00","city":"Seattle","customerName":"JONES JACKIE L","state":"WA","updatedBy":"Bill Armstrong "}',
 '{"updatedDate":"2023-12-29T19:52:01.276227+00:00","city":"Boise","customerName":"JOHNSON BOB","state":"ID","updatedBy":"Brian Smith "}'])
)

-- query
select json_extract_scalar(json, '$.customerName') customerName,
       json_extract_scalar(json, '$.city') city,
       json_extract_scalar(json, '$.state') state,
       json_extract_scalar(json, '$.updatedBy') updatedBy,
       json_extract_scalar(json, '$.updatedDate') updatedDate
from dataset
, unnest(properties_textarray) as t(json);


Thanks for the response!  Two questions:  If the JSON objects in the array are variable both if they exist or the elements within the JSON object will this map approach fail if the element doesn't exist?  Also in the example code can you explain 'as t(json)?

@JeffA " will map approach fail if the element doesn't exist?" - no, I use element_at specifically for this reason, it will return null if key is not present, but you should now that this approach will not work as is for array(varchar), it should be adjusted a bit. "can you explain as t(json)" - it is the alias for "virtual table" which is "produced" by unnest, that's it.
